# Can't acquire add-in without personal account

Tags: outlook-addin, appsource

I have developed an Outlook add-in that I have published in the store (https://appsource.microsoft.com/da-dk/product/office/WA104381386 ). The add-in is targeted Office365 work accounts.
However when users try to acquire the add-in they are asked to switch from their work account to a personal account. 
I want the users to be able to get the add-in just with their Office365 account without having to switch to (and possible create) a personal account.

Not sure if this is something that I can configure in the add-in manifest or in the Seller Dashboard, but so far not been able to find any documentation on this.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a brand new test tenant (or use existing)
2. From within Outlook (web) opened settings -> Manage add-ins
3. Search for MeetingRoomMap -> click ‘get it’ (transferred to
   https://appsource.microsoft.com/da-dk/product/office/WA104381386 )
4. Click free trial
5. Transferred to login page that only accepts personal account (account from tenant not accepted) – see screenshot attached.
   [image: work account not accepted]

If I choose ‘Get it now’ instead of ‘free trial’, I get this message: “Change to your personal account. If you want to proceed you must enter the email attached to your personal account”.
I’m not able to get the add-in without entering a personal account (screenshot in Danish).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, purchasing add-in licenses is currently only available via Microsoft Accounts.

Users will be able to acquire trial licenses with their O365 Accounts via the Outlook store, but they will have to swap to MSA for the full purchase.

If you're looking to handle purchase for O365 accounts, I'd recommend reading our GTM guidance on freemium setups. 
https://dev.office.com/blogs/gtm-how-to-monetize-with-office-add-ins-and-apps